# SQL query left join issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I am making a query but it is not working properly.

My table details are as follows:

**Subarea:**
id
Fieldsofstudy

**student_subarea:**
id primary key,
student_id ,
student_subarea   Foreign key to subarea id and the student_subarea.

**ASK:**
What I want to accomplish is to obtain all fields of study in one column and in another column the id of the student if he is in the class. Otherwise, show null or something.

```
SELECT a.`id` ,  a.`name` , a.`area_id` , u. * 
FROM  `subarea` a
LEFT JOIN student_subarea u ON u.subarea_id = a.id
WHERE u.student_id =50
OR u.student_id IS NULL
```

Doing this is not helping at all. I tried to use functions and subqueries without any success. Could some help me.

Comment: You might want to update your answer to include what kind of SQL server you are using, as well as any error messages you're getting when you try to run the code that you supplied.

Comment: I am not getting any error. I am just selecting in the wrong data over and over and over and I don't know how to get what I said before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general rule for `left join` and filtering is to put the filtering clauses in the `on` clause for all but the first table.  So this may do what you want:

```
SELECT a.`id`, a.`name`, a.`area_id`, u. * 
FROM `subarea` a LEFT JOIN
     student_subarea u
     ON u.subarea_id = a.id AND u.student_id = 50;
```

How do you remember this logic?  A `left join` returns all rows from the first table even when there is no match on the second table.  That appears to be what you want.

The problem with your logic is that students *other than* student `50` match the logic.  So, those rows get filtered out.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. Good explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Move the filter criteria to the JOIN

```
SELECT a.`id` ,  a.`name` , a.`area_id` , u. * 
FROM  `subarea` a
LEFT JOIN student_subarea u 
  ON u.subarea_id = a.id
     AND u.student_id =50
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the condition on the student ID inside the join condition, not in the `where` clause:

```
SELECT    a.id,  a.name , a.area_id, u.* 
FROM      subarea a
LEFT JOIN student_subarea u
       ON u.subarea_id = a.id
      AND u.student_id = 50
```